# Laravel Sanctum Authorization outside server problem

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, authorization

I created 2 different laravel project

1. client
2. server

in the client-side i make request to my server-side and then the server-side returning the Bearer token to the client-side, then in the client-side i use the bearer token to make request the server-side where its route guarded by auth:sanctum middleware but it ended up returning Route[login] not defined to client-side. i use postman to make all the request

Workflow:

**1. make request to server-side, server-side returning the bearer token**

Client-side:

```
    public function index()
    {
        return Http::post('http://server.test/api/v1/init', [
            'db_username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'db_password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'db_exp_time' => 60
        ]);

        // $check = Http::withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Bearer 1|sZR5OCw2RedtdsWc5t7ibIXNTaayjqzOwyxo8iq4DA'])->post('http://server.test/api/v1/check', [
        //     'db_exp_time' => 60
        // ]);

        //return $check 
    }
```

Client-side route

```
Route::prefix('v1')->group(function(){
    Route::apiResource('/products', ProductController::class);
});
```

Server-side

```
public function init(Request $request){
        $hash = Hash::make($request);
        $id = Temp_credential::create([
            'username' => $request->db_username,
            'password' => $request->db_password,
            'exp_time' => Carbon::now()->timestamp + $request->db_exp_time,
            'key' => $hash
        ]);

        $token = $id->createToken('myapptoken')->plainTextToken;

        return [
            'key' => Crypt::encryptString($hash),
            'tokens' => $token
        ];
    }
```

**2. client-side request to the server-side where its route guarded by auth:sanctum**

Client-side

```
public function index()
    {
        // return Http::post('http://server.test/api/v1/init', [
        //     'db_username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
        //     'db_password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        //     'db_exp_time' => 60
        // ]);

        $check = Http::withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Bearer 1|sZR5OCw2RedtdsWc5t7ibIXNTaayjqzOwyxo8iq4DA'])->post('http://server.test/api/v1/check', [
            'db_exp_time' => 60
        ]);

        return $check;
    }
```

Server-side

```
public function check(Request $request){

        return 'check';
}
```

Server-side check route

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function(){
        Route::post('/check', [CredentialController::class, 'check']);
    });
```

after i did this, my client-side return me Route[login] not defined to client-side.
[image]

but if i tried to request from server-side directly, it return the "check"
[image]

i want to know can laravel sanctum do the authorization and if not what authentication/authorization you suggest for this laravel application

Comment: both methods are index? Can you provide a cleaner code?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is good.

Looking at the last image you have, the bearer token should not be in the header section, it should be in the authorization section, while you select the auth type to Bearer token.

more details here
https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#specifying-authorization-details

Also, hit **save** on the top right of the postman before making the request so that postman should not make a request to previously save URL.

Run `php artisan route:list` to see all the routes available.

This should give you some insights to solve your problem.